# R get_followers() more than 75,000 not possible, even with retryonratelimit = TRUE

Tags: r, rtweet

I want to download all followers of a Twitter user with the function `get_followers` from the `rtweet` package.
With an older version of the `rtweet` package, this worked without any problems, although it took a long time.
Since I updated the package (current version is 1.0.2), I only get the first 75,000 followers, even though I set the `retryonratelimit`-option to TRUE.
The function downloads the first 75,000 followers, then waits 15 minutes and then ends the download process without any message.
Here you can see my example code:

```
library(rtweet)

# I have authenticated myself with auth_setup_default()

df_follower <- get_followers("CDU",n = 800000,retryonratelimit = TRUE)

> df_follower 
# A tibble: 75,000 × 2
   from_id             to_id
   <chr>               <chr>
```

Can someone explain me where the problem is and how I can download all followers?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is a bug fixed in the devel branch of the package (I think you asked in the issue tracker https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/732).
In the next release this will be fixed.

In the rtweet version 1.1 this was fixed.

Comment: Yes, I asked the question on Github. Many thanks for the solution!